# How to know which dictionary has the most key in my list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionary of this form

```
my_list = [{'notion': 'example'}, {'notion': 'another example', 'type': 'value'}, {'ex': 'other_ex'}]
```

I want to get the index of the "biggest" dictionary of my list. For now I have this code:

```
size = 0
for i, elem in enumerate(my_list):
   if len(elem) > size:
      index_to_save = i
      size = len(elem)
```

Now I'm pretty sure there's a more quicker and pythonic way to achieve this goal.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`max()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) with `key=len`:

```
>>> my_list = [{'notion': 'example'}, {'notion': 'another example', 'type': 'value'}, {'ex': 'other_ex'}]
>>> max(my_list, key=len)
{'notion': 'another example', 'type': 'value'}
```

If you have multiple dictionaries with the same max number of keys, and you want to return them all, then you can filter with a list comprehension:

```
my_list = [
    {"notion": "example"},
    {"notion": "another example", "type": "value"},
    {"notion": "another example", "type1": "value2"},
    {"ex": "other_ex"},
]

max_length = max(map(len, my_list))
# or max(len(x) for x in my_list)

print([x for x in my_list if len(x) == max_length])
# [{'notion': 'another example', 'type': 'value'}, {'notion': 'another example', 'type1': 'value2'}]
```

Or another approach which groups by length with a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), then takes the values of the maximum length key:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from operator import itemgetter

my_list = [
    {"notion": "example"},
    {"notion": "another example", "type": "value"},
    {"notion": "another example", "type1": "value2"},
    {"ex": "other_ex"},
]

lengths = defaultdict(list)
for x in my_list:
    lengths[len(x)].append(x)

print(max(lengths.items(), key=itemgetter(0))[1])
# [{'notion': 'another example', 'type': 'value'}, {'notion': 'another example', 'type1': 'value2'}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you mentioned you're ok with a pandas solution, here is one: You can get the key count using pandas nunique:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame(my_list).nunique()
```

output

```
notion    2
type      1
ex        1
dtype: int64

pd.DataFrame(my_list).nunique().to_dict()                                                                                                                                           
# {'notion': 2, 'type': 1, 'ex': 1}

pd.DataFrame(my_list).nunique().idxmax()                                                                                                                                            
# 'notion'
```